# How to define entry point for react native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm just getting started with react native and have created a base app with `create-react-native-app`.

I did some restructuring and made a few new folders and renamed the App.js to Home.js. I modified the `app.json` to contain an entry point that references the new `Home.js` file. When I load the app, nothing happens. There's no error, it just stays on the expo screen.

```
.
 -components
 -screens
    -Home
        Home.js
 -config
 -node_modules
 -tests
 app.json
```

app.json file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion" : "23.0.0",
    "entryPoint" : "./screens/Home/Home.js"
  }
}
```

How do you define the entry point of the app?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

if you are using Expo, you have to specify the entrypoint in your `app.json` file like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "entryPoint": "./src/app/index.js"
  }
}
```

then, inside that file you need to register the app with `Expo.registerRootComponent(YOUR_MAIN_APP_COMPONENT)`

```
import Expo from 'expo'
...

class App extends Component {
  ...
}

export default Expo.registerRootComponent(App);
```

this way you can add your entry file wherever you want.

Comment: I could only get this to work using `Expo.registerRootComponent(App);` instead of `export default Expo.registerRootComponent(App);`. With the latter i kept getting the error, `undefined is not an object`.

Comment: `import Expo from 'expo'` is not working. You have to `import { registerRootComponent } from "expo"`.

Comment: This answer is outdated now

Comment: what would be the current answer so ? @JohnMiller

Comment: This has changed. The current approach is to set `"main"` on `package.json`. See the documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/#what-if-i-want-to-name-my-main-app-file-something-other-than-appjs

Answer (score 27):

You need to update the `app.json` so that the `entryPoint` is the new path to the `App.js`.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "entryPoint": "./src/App.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

However using `Expo.registerRootComponent(App)` causes the following error in SDK 32:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.default.registerRootComponent')
```

It can be **fixed** by importing `registerRootComponent` explicitly, rather than trying to access it via `Expo.registerRootComponent`.

Here is a sample `App.js`.

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

class App extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export default registerRootComponent(App);
```

Comment: For newer sdks (like mine), import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo' worked! Thks!

Answer (score 26):

#### For Expo Projects

According to the current Expo documentation, if you want a different entry point than the `App.js` file, you can update the `package.json` - add a `main` field with the path to the desired entry point. Then inside the entry point file you'll have to also have to register the **root** component of the app. Expo was doing this automatically, when the entry point wasn't specified and was the `App.js` file

package.json

```
{
 "main": "my/customEntry.js"
}
```

entryPointFile.js

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import MyRootComponent from './MyRoot';

registerRootComponent(MyRootComponent);
```

---

What if I want to name my main app file something other than App.js? - https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/#what-if-i-want-to-name-my

Answer (score 7):

If your project is in **managed workflow** setup (the default one), as stated in the [doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/), you must import the registerRootComponent and call it with your root component as argument, in the file you wish to be the main one:

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

const AnyName() { ... } // Your root component

registerRootComponent(AnyName)
```

And then, in your **package.json** file, change the "main" to this file relative path, like

```
{
  "main": "src/main.js"
}
```

Comment: this works in sep, 2023.

Answer (score 3):

The entry point can be found in node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js..
This is in Expo Typescript...

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
 import App from '../../src/App';
 registerRootComponent(App);
```

In this you can change your entry point.  Initially it is  set to App, Look the import statement where that component is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

I created project by react-native-script. In default entrypoint of app (App.js), you export App which import from your entry.

```
- node_modules
- App.js
- build
    - main.js
```

File App.js:

```
import App from './build/main'
export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer to put all sources in a separated folder, for instance **src/**, and I found a different solution:

1. in my package.json, generated by expo cli, I see that main attribute is *node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js*.
2. I copied *node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js* to *src/expoAppEntry.js* and just changed the App import to `import App from './App';` so it points to my *src/App.tsx`
3. then of course I changed the package.json main attribute to *src/expoAppEntry.js*.

See a working example here https://github.com/fibo/tris3d-app/blob/master/src/expoAppEntry.js

Comment: Really bad solution IMO

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using **Expo** with **typescript**, you dont have to add .tsx at the end of the entrypoint in app.json. For example your entrypoint can be:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "entryPoint": "./app/components/AppEntryPoint/App.component",
    "name": "Sample App",
     ...
     }
  ...
}
```

In this example the name of entrypoint component is App.Component.tsx. But **not mentioning the extension will also work**. Apart from this, in the root component,  writing `export default registerRootComponent(AppComponent)` or `registerRootComponent(AppComponent)` both should work as exporting a component from a file only means that other files can use it as well. Not writing it should not be an issue here because we have mentioned in app.json that this is the root component. App.json will look up and start building the structure of the app from there itself.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

In `package.json` add

```
"main": "src/App.tsx",
```

Then in your `App.tsx` you need to register

```
registerRootComponent(App);
```

Idea is in package you point to where the App is being registered and NOT the actual App component, but where you are registering.

In my case i have both App.tsx and registration happening in same file and works fine.

More info: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

Comment: For anyone confused about the other answers: this is supported [for SDK 49 and above](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/#what-if-i-want-to-name-my-main-app-file-something-other-than-appjs). For [SDK 48 and below](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#custom-main-entry-point-in-packagejson-is-not-supported-for-sdk-48-and-below), it's recommended to stick with an `index.js` in the project root that references your app component placed wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

When using expo, instead of having the main entry point be in app/index.js, I wanted it the main entrypoint to be App.tsx at the root of the project. I merely added this line to my package.json (found from comparing the template code for a blank expo project):

```
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
```