# Change Expo React Native App.js to different file

Tags: react-native, expo

At the moment `npm start` looks in `App.js`. How do I change this to a different file?

Comment: ou mean you want to change the extension?

Comment: Duplicate of [defining expo entryPoint in app.json does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886508/defining-expo-entrypoint-in-app-json-does-not-work)

Comment: @hongdevelop I meant to put App.js in a different folder- turns out you explicitly have to register the root element in this case

Answer (score 3):

You can use `entryPoint` property in `app.json`.

Check this : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/

Comment: That actually isn't enough but I found that my question is a duplicate and that answer works- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886508/defining-expo-entrypoint-in-app-json-does-not-work