# What is the difference between package.json main and app.config.js expo.entryPoint?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to TypeScript, React Native and Expo, and am confused how you configure the main entry point.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742280/how-to-define-entry-point-for-react-native-app) talks about both configuration properties.

The Expo docs also mention both:

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#entrypoint
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package.json` `main` is used as a fallback to the `app.config` `entryPoint`. You should be defining the entry point in `app.config`.

You can see how it has been handled here: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/pull/750/files, and you can see a discussion about this change [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4613)